# Drawing Points with GPU via GLSL

Tags: python, gpu

I'm trying to draw a series of points using GLSL, but I'm doing something wrong when defining my shaders:

```
import bpy
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader

# Define the vertex shader
vertex_shader = """
    in vec3 pos;
    uniform mat4 modelview_matrix;
    void main() {
        gl_Position = modelview_matrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);
        gl_PointSize = 5.0;
    }
"""

# Define the fragment shader
fragment_shader = """
    out vec4 frag_color;
    void main() {
        frag_color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
"""

# Create a shader program
shader = gpu.types.GPUShader(vertex_shader, fragment_shader)

# Create a batch for the points
points = [(1.0, 2.0, 0.0), (-1.0, -2.0, 0.0)]  # Example points
batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'POINTS', {"pos": points})

# Set up the drawing context
shader.bind()
shader.uniform_matrix("modelview_matrix", 4, bpy.context.region_data.view_matrix)


def draw():
    gpu.state.depth_test_set('LESS_EQUAL')
    gpu.state.depth_mask_set(True)
    batch.draw(shader)
    gpu.state.depth_mask_set(False)


bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')
```

The code above results in the following error:

````
---> 24 shader = gpu.types.GPUShader(vertex_shader, fragment_shader)
     26 # Create a batch for the points
     27 points = [(1.0, 2.0, 0.0), (-1.0, -2.0, 0.0)]  # Example points

Exception: Shader Compile Error, see console for more details
```
````

Comment: The shader create method changed in blender 4.0, see: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html

Comment: This uses the new method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
import bpy
import gpu
from gpu.types import GPUShaderCreateInfo, GPUStageInterfaceInfo
from gpu.shader import create_from_info
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader

# Define the vertex shader
vertex_shader = """
    void main() {
        gl_Position = viewProjectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    }
"""

# Define the fragment shader
fragment_shader = """
    void main() {
        FragColor = color;
    }
"""

shader_info = GPUShaderCreateInfo()
shader_info.push_constant('MAT4', "viewProjectionMatrix")
shader_info.push_constant('VEC4', "color")
shader_info.vertex_in(0, 'VEC3', "position")
shader_info.fragment_out(0, 'VEC4', "FragColor")
shader_info.vertex_source(vertex_shader)
shader_info.fragment_source(fragment_shader)
shader = create_from_info(shader_info)
del shader_info

# Create a batch for the points
points = [(1.0, 2.0, 0.0), (-1.0, -2.0, 0.0)]  # Example points
batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'POINTS', {"position": points})


def draw():
    gpu.state.depth_test_set('LESS_EQUAL')
    gpu.state.depth_mask_set(True)
    
    shader.bind()
    matrix = bpy.context.region_data.perspective_matrix
    shader.uniform_float("viewProjectionMatrix", matrix)
    shader.uniform_float("color", (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
    batch.draw(shader)

    gpu.state.depth_mask_set(False)


bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')
```